# Formatting Cell Data

Tags: css, html, html-table

I am writing a fairly (should be) simple HTML5 site that is a HTML5 table of the Periodic Table of elements. I am trying to format the data of each cell (each element) to show the abbreviation of the element, the atomic number and the atomic weight. I wrote a few CSS classes to format these cells in the table but it renders each piece of information on a new line in the cell. How can I get the data all on the same line so it fits the site of the cell?

These are the CSS classes:

```
/* class for element abbreviation */
h2
{
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
}

h6.anum
{
text-align:left;
vertical-align:top;
font-size:8px;
}

h6.aweight
{
text-align:right;
vertical-align:top;
font-size:8px;
}
```

And this is the relevant entry in the HTML5 code:

```
<td><h6 class="anum">1</h6><h2>H</h2><h6 class="aweight">1.01<h6></td>
```

This displays more or less like this in the cell:

1

H

1.01

I would like text to be on the same line with the 1 and 1.01 in the left and right corner respectively.

I will admit this is probably done incredibly poorly from a design standpoint but this is my first HTML class so... I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

`h1` - `h6` in HTML are **block elements**, meaning they usually stretch out to fill their container and have a blank line on either side of them. If you want them to sit next to each other, perhaps on the same line, you will need to set `display: inline` on them to coerce them to regular inline elements. You may also need to adjust the `margin` to make them sit more closely to one another.

Example CSS:

```
h1 {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0.25em auto;
    /* More styles */
}
```

However, this isn't necessarily the way I would do it. Personally, I would put these in a `div` with `position: relative` and then absolutely position the `h6` elements the way I want them. [See example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Sj9/)